# Does azure search indexer offer better performance comparing to the POST API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We use azure search indexers to update our search indexes. However, as underlying data coming from different tables, we have to maintain lookup tables for search indexers, which is quite a headache for us.

I realised that I could do this:

- Have a webjob looping through a search index in 1000 or 2000 item
  batches.
- For each batch, check various database tables to see if data is changed.
- If change is found within a batch, I can create new 500 item batches to merge the changed fields the search indexes via POST API.
- If new item or deleted items are found, I will call Add and Delete operation accordingly.

Benefit:

1. No need to maintain lookup tables any more
2. No need for indexers.

Problem:
Not sure.

Will performance becoming worse? If we ignore parallel indexer run (as webjob can be run in parallel as well), will indexer achieve better performance than HTTP Post API? This is the only part performance could getting worse in my mind.

Comment: What is your objective in making the change? Are you writing some form of change data capture?

Comment: Hi @Tarzan, if you know the amount of data and efforts needed to maintain these look up tables, you will understand my objective